# Where are Pypi packages installed by default?

Tags: python

I am new to programming and Python and what's really bothering me is that on my Mac, I'm used to knowing exactly where everything is and what's in every folder, but doing things through the command line is very different, so I don't know where things like Python Packages are being installed to by default.

According to the Pypi site, the packages are installed here: /usr/local/lib/python2.3/site-packages'

However when I cd to /usr/local/lib/, all I see in this folder are 'wx-python unicode', which I'm guessing was an accident on my part because I forgot to activate my virtual environment when I installed it?

Why is nothing in my /lib/ folder?

Comment: `pip show package_name` will tell you where it was installed (assuming you used pip to install it).

Answer (score 1):

If you ever want to know where a module source file is located:

```
import some_module

print some_module.__file__
```

Comment: OK thank, shouldn't everything I install through pip be kept in the same sub folder by default?

Comment: yes pip does have a default installation directory, on my OSX setup everything I install with pip goes to /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ and I have almost no packages in /usr/local/lib FWIW.